# Can not re render events fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I try to reset events by updating new data from server but it didn't work and i don't know why. It seems everything is ok.

I remove all events first and add new source to it.

Thank you.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/time_slots/bulk',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      time_slot: JSON.stringify(timeSlots),
      user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(timeSlots) {
      calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
      timeSlots.forEach(function(el) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', el);
      });
      window.currentTimeSlots = timeSlots;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot title of event so it can not render correctly.